# Sending data stream from python program to web app

Tags: python, ajax, django, server

I have a python program appending lines to a .csv file every few seconds. I also have a web app that was created using Django. My goal is to continuously read the data from the python program as it runs and display it on the website without having to refresh.

My proposed solution is to send the python output to a server using requests.put(), and then read from the server using AJAX.

1.) Is this the best solution, or is there a better manner to connect the program and the site.

2.) If this is a good solution, what's the easiest way to get a server running to POST, PUT, and GET from? It can be local and will never expect heavy traffic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reading from csv is not good solution,message quene is suitable solution for this context。

1. python program can post a data message to django when adding lines
   to csv.
2. django webapp can send data message to browser when getting
   message by SSE or socket.io lib